# Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating a ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I want to pass a URL parameter to a method's parameter of type string (not a model). This used to be done using a `[FromQuery]` in the methods call's parameter section, i.e -

```
public async Task<person> getPerson([FromQuery] string name)
```

However, it is not part of the new SDK. What is the new method for doing this?

Comment: _"however, it is not part of the SDK"_ Not sure what do you mean by "SDK" but `FromQueryAttribute` is part of the [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I believe your link required the attribute to be placed on the model and not used in the method - e.g, public async Task<person> getPerson([FromQuery] name)

Comment: @GuruStron - It is not part of the SDK with the same usage as before unless I am not understanding something. Can you illustrate how I can use it without adding it to a model?

Comment: FromQuery targets parameters (in methods) as well as properties (on models)

Comment: It is also part of asp.net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources

Comment: @GuruStron You're correct. It is working now. I am not sure why. I ran a build clean which may have resolved the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would suggest removing this post since ,while similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.